# How do I search Libraries in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

How do you include libraries in file searches within in Eclipse?

I'm trying to include the Android source code library in my search using CTRL+H, and can't find an option to do so.

Comment: I do no think this is possible unless you have the android source code as a proejct in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InstaSearch Eclipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch) will index and search inside jars that have source attachements. This is not enabled by default but can be set in preferences.

Comment: Hello, is there any plugin for android studio?

Answer (score -2):

You can add the libraries in your peoject using

goto

project->properties->JavaBuildpath

you'll see libraries option there you can add the libraries from this point.

shafali