# Using Eclipse PyDev's search function with external libraries

Tags: python, eclipse, search, pydev

I find PyDev's search function incredibly useful and use it regularly to navigate around my projects. I've got my interpreters set up correctly so PyDev knows about the external libraries that my code uses, and even lets me follow references into the library modules. This is great, obviously, but I also want to be able to search the external libraries like I can search my own code.

There's a similar question pertaining to Java development here: [How do I search Libraries in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969503/how-do-i-search-libraries-in-eclipse)

Is there anything out there for PyDev?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use two different approaches to allow searching in my library code:

- When I am using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/), I keep all my code under `myproject/src` and add it and `myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` as pydev source folders.  (Be sure to setup your python interpreter to `myproject/bin/python` as well)
- In other cases, I use two different pydev projects.  The first (`myproject`) includes my code.  The second one is called `myproject-lib` and includes the libraries as it's source paths (`.../site_packages`).  The first project references the second projects (and usually I keep both of them in one workspace).  This works great with virtualenv, but I believe that you can actually create a pydev project in your system-wide python.  Make sure you use the same python interpreter  in both projects.

Now you can quickly and easily use **Open Resource** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and the **Globals Browser** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to lookup your libs.

Comment: Awesome. I tend to use the PyPI layout for each of my projects (`src_root`, `tests`, `docs`, `README`, `setup.py` etc. in the top level) so I can't add `site-packages` as a second source folder. But the second project technique works rather well. The **Open Resource** shortcut is also very neat, thanks!

Comment: If you use multiple projects, like Udi said on the second option, you can also use search (Ctrl-H): click "Working set" on the "Scope" area, click "Choose" button, "Selected Working Sets" option, "New", "Resource" on "Working set type" and choose the projects you want to search within.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid PyDev doesn't support this yet. I created feature request for this at https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7405 Meanwhile you could link folders of external libraries to your project.

Comment: Thanks Piotr. It would be a good feature... Even better if there was an option to 'also include libs' or similar. In the mean time adding the root of the libraries as a separate project works well.